# PHP MVC query to get all existing rows is returning only 1 row

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a working query but its only returning 1 row - where or what can I do to return *all* existing rows?

Model:

```
    public function getInfo() {

    $info_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `km_info` WHERE ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW()) AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW())) AND status = '1'");

    if ($info_query->num_rows){
        return array(
            'info_id'       => $info_query->row['info_id'],
            'name'          => $info_query->row['name'],
            'amount'        => $info_query->row['amount'],
            'date_start'    => $info_query->row['date_start'],
            'date_end'      => $info_query->row['date_end'],
            'status'        => $info_query->row['status'],
            'date_added'    => $info_query->row['date_added']
        );
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
        $info_options = $this->model_extension_total_info->getInfo();

    if ($info_options){
        $json['info_options'] = array();

        $json['info_options'][] = array(
            'info_id'     => $info_options['info_id'],
            'name'          => $info_options['name'],
            'amount'        => $info_options['amount'],
            'date_start'    => $info_options['date_start'],
            'date_end'      => $info_options['date_end'],
            'status'        => $info_options['status'],
            'date_added'    => $info_options['date_added']
        );
    }
```

When I try foreach() in the controller, I still only get one row.:

```
        foreach ($info_options as $info) {
            var_dump($info_options['name']);exit;
            //var_dump($info_options['name']); results: Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' 
        }
```

In the model, when I dump:
`$info_query` I get 9 -- which is all of the rows I'm expecting.

Not particularly certain what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looping over the result. Not in model nor in the controller. Though I don't know why you'd do this twice. Maybe I'm just not understanding your code.

Model:

```
$data = [];    

if ($info_query->num_rows){
    foreach ($info_query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = array(
            'info_id'       => $row['info_id'],
            'name'          => $row['name'],
            'amount'        => $row['amount'],
            'date_start'    => $row['date_start'],
            'date_end'      => $row['date_end'],
            'status'        => $row['status'],
            'date_added'    => $row['date_added']
        );
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Controller:

```
$info_options = $this->model_extension_total_info->getInfo();
$json['info_options'] = array();

if ($info_options){
    foreach ($info_options as $info) {

        $json['info_options'][] = array(
            'info_id'     => $info['info_id'],
            'name'          => $info['name'],
            'amount'        => $info['amount'],
            'date_start'    => $info['date_start'],
            'date_end'      => $info['date_end'],
            'status'        => $info['status'],
            'date_added'    => $info['date_added']
        );
    }
}
```

Technically, you don't have to loop at all. You can just:

```
public function getInfo() {

    $info_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `km_info` WHERE ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW()) AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW())) AND status = '1'");

    if ($info_query->num_rows){
        return $info_query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
$info_options = $this->model_extension_total_info->getInfo();

// and that's it, just do whatever you need with $info_options
```

Comment: Is it required to loop in both?  When I add your controller loop, I get `Warning: Illegal string offset 'variable_name'` for all variables.  Going to try the model bit now; I think you've edited since I originally seen this post

Comment: Yeah sorry, this is codeigniter right? I haven't worked with it in a bit. You don't have to loop twice, your code just looked like you were doing the same thing twice. You can just pass $info_options in the controller right to your view, I didn't know why you were repackaging it into arrays.

Comment: No, Opencart, but this is not native code.. which is why I'm asking for help.  Trying to add functionality that doesn't presently exist. What do you mean by **You can just pass $info_options in the controller right to your view, I didn't know why you were repackaging it into arrays** - still learning my way through MVC.  The controller code yielded the same error.

Comment: Frankly you don't really have to loop over anything at all. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Think something within Opencart is interfering with this.. When I run your updated code, I still get illegal string offsets. `var_dump($info_query->rows);exit;` shows me everything I am trying to get.  When I add the foreach() loop back, the errors go away but still only 1 result. Puzzled.

Comment: Operator error... forgot to hit save on the controller!! Thanks again for your help!